# WordPress 4.7 - Custom Video Header – Stop Autoplay

Tags: video-header

I am using WordPress’ latest custom video header feature. Anybody has an idea how to stop autoplay? Checked filters but did not find a way to disable autoplay.

`/wp-includes/js/wp-custom-header.js` has the default settings. However not getting any clue how I may override it without editing core files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a need to override any core files. You can just use javascript to stop autoplaying the video.

I tested the following code on **Twenty Seventeen** theme and it works fine.
For example:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( document ).on( 'wp-custom-header-video-loaded', function() {
        $("#wp-custom-header-video").attr('autoplay',false);
    });
});
```

This does the trick.

Comment: That works thanks. The thing is I was trying same snippet in Twenty Seventeen theme's `global.js` file. Apparently... I did not notice that I was placing it outside of `document.ready` and hence it was not working. Thank you very much.