# where can i add custom script to stop header video from autoplay

Tags: customization, media, headers

How can I add the custom script from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/254249/199479) to my site to stop the custom video header from autoplaying?

```php
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( document ).on( 'wp-custom-header-video-loaded', function() {
        $("#wp-custom-header-video").attr('autoplay',false);
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to enqueue a script from the theme functions.php file - see how here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own theme or a child theme then you can add this in script tags to one of your templates. I'd suggest your footer template, just after the call to `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`

```html
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    jQuery( document ).on( 'wp-custom-header-video-loaded', function() {
        jQuery("#wp-custom-header-video").attr('autoplay',false);
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that I've changed `$` to `jQuery` since WordPress's jQuery is installed in no-conflict mode by default and does not define `$`.

Alternatively you can enqueue it as an inline script from a plugin or theme

```php
function wp_custom_header_video_autoplay_false() {
    wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery', "<script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    jQuery( document ).on( 'wp-custom-header-video-loaded', function() {
        jQuery("#wp-custom-header-video").attr('autoplay',false);
    });
});
</script>
");
};
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_custom_header_video_autoplay_false' );
```